# Unity stops responding upon hitting play only when I uncomment a method

Tags: unity-game-engine, playback

When I uncomment the line "ConnectMaze(maze)" in the Start() method, Unity instantly stops responding when I hit play. None of the Debug.Log statements show up in the console. If I comment out that specific line, I am able to see the Debug.Log statements in the console and Unity does respond.  I am thinking that there could be an infinite loop in the ConnectMaze while loop, however wouldn't the Debug.Log statements prior to the loop still show up in the console? Below is the code that is causing the issue.

```cs
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class MazeBase : MonoBehaviour {

    public const int mazeLength = 11;
    private int[,] maze = new int[mazeLength,mazeLength];
    private int numWalls;
    // Use this for initialization

    void Start () {
        Debug.Log ("Initialize Start");
        InitializeMaze (maze);
        Debug.Log ("Initialize End");
        Debug.Log ("Connectivity Start");
        ConnectMaze (maze);
        Debug.Log ("Connectivity End");
        MazeGenerator.Generate (transform,maze);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    }
    private void CreateMazeBlock(){
        Vector3 mousePos = Input.mousePosition;
        mousePos.z = 10;
        Vector3 cameraPos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint (mousePos);
        int cameraPosX = (int)Mathf.Round (cameraPos.x);
        int cameraPosZ = (int)Mathf.Round (cameraPos.z);
        if (maze [cameraPosX, cameraPosZ] != 1) {
            maze [cameraPosX, cameraPosZ] = 1;
            MazeGenerator.GenerateSingleBlock (transform, cameraPosX, cameraPosZ);
        }
    }

    private void DeleteMazeBlock(){
        Vector3 mousePos = Input.mousePosition;
        mousePos.z = 10;
        Vector3 cameraPos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint (mousePos);
        int cameraPosX = (int)Mathf.Round (cameraPos.x);
        int cameraPosZ = (int)Mathf.Round (cameraPos.z);
        if (maze [cameraPosX, cameraPosZ] == 1) {
            maze [cameraPosX, cameraPosZ] = 0;
            MazeGenerator.DeleteSingleBlock (cameraPosX, cameraPosZ);
        }
    }
    private void InitializeMaze(int[,] maze){
        for (int i = 0; i < mazeLength; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < mazeLength; j++) {
                if (i == 0 || i == mazeLength - 1 || j == 0 || j == mazeLength - 1) {
                    maze [i, j] = -1;
                    numWalls++;
                } else if (Random.Range (0, 100) < 50) {
                    bool createWall = true;
                    //Following if statements prevent a 2x2 square of walls
                    if (IsWall (maze, i - 1, j - 1) && IsWall (maze, i - 1, j) && IsWall (maze, i, j - 1)) {
                        createWall = false;
                    }else if (IsWall (maze, i - 1, j + 1) && IsWall (maze, i - 1, j) && IsWall (maze, i, j + 1)) {
                        createWall = false;
                    }else if (IsWall (maze, i + 1, j - 1) && IsWall (maze, i + 1, j) && IsWall (maze, i, j - 1)) {
                        createWall = false;
                    }else if (IsWall (maze, i + 1, j + 1) && IsWall (maze, i + 1, j) && IsWall (maze, i, j + 1)) {
                        createWall = false;
                    }
                    if(createWall){
                        maze [i, j] = -1;
                        numWalls++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }
    private bool IsWall(int[,] maze, int i, int j){
        return maze [i, j] < 0;
    }
    private void ConnectMaze(int[,] maze){
        Debug.Log ("GetNextTile Start");
        ArrayList startTile = GetNextTile (maze,0);
        Debug.Log ("GetNextTile End");
        int startX = (int)startTile[0];
        int startZ = (int)startTile[1];
        int numberOfFloods = 1;
        Debug.Log ("Flood Fill 1 Start");
        int numFound = FloodFill(maze,startX,startZ,numberOfFloods);
        Debug.Log ("Flood Fill 1 End");
        while (numFound != (mazeLength * mazeLength) - numWalls) {
            ArrayList nextWallTile = GetNextTile (maze, 1);
            int wallX = (int)nextWallTile[0];
            int wallZ = (int)nextWallTile[1];
            maze [wallX, wallZ] = 0;
            numWalls--;
            numberOfFloods++;
            int numFound2 = FloodFill(maze,startX,startZ,numberOfFloods);
            if(numFound2 == (mazeLength*mazeLength)-numWalls){
                break;
            }
            if (numFound2 - numFound > 1) {
                numFound = numFound2;
            } else {
                maze [wallX, wallZ] = 2;
                numWalls++;
            }
            int temp = (mazeLength * mazeLength) - numWalls;
            Debug.Log ("Number of empty tiles: " + temp);
            Debug.Log ("Number of tiles found: " + numFound);
        }
    }
    private int FloodFill(int[,] maze, int x, int z,int value){
        int numEmptyTilesFound = 0;
        if (x < 0 || z < 0 || x >= mazeLength || z >= mazeLength) {
            return 0;
        }
        if (maze [x, z] == -1 || maze [x, z] == value) {
            return 0;
        }
        maze [x, z] = value;
        numEmptyTilesFound++;
        numEmptyTilesFound += FloodFill (maze, x - 1, z, value);
        numEmptyTilesFound += FloodFill (maze, x + 1, z, value);
        numEmptyTilesFound += FloodFill (maze, x, z - 1, value);
        numEmptyTilesFound += FloodFill (maze, x, z + 1, value);
        return numEmptyTilesFound;
    } 
    private ArrayList GetNextTile(int[,] maze,int value){
        int startX = 0;
        int startZ = 0;
        bool search = true;
        for (int i = 0; i < mazeLength; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < mazeLength; j++) {
                if (maze [i, j] == value) {
                    startX = i;
                    startZ = j;
                    search = false;
                }
                if(!search){
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(!search){
                break;
            }
        }
        ArrayList startingPoint = new ArrayList ();
        startingPoint.Add (startX);
        startingPoint.Add (startZ);
        return startingPoint;
    }
}
```

Comment: Quick question. You said the debug statements don't show when the line in question is not commented out. Do you see either of the debug statements printed from lines Debug.Log ("GetNextTile Start") and Debug.Log ("Number of tiles found: " + numFound) ? And the output stops after that? Or do none of these show at all when the line is enabled ?

Comment: The Debug.Log statements in Start() do show up when ConnectMaze() is commented out. When ConnectMaze() is enabled, none of the Debug.Log statements appear in the console, not even the ones in Start().

Comment: I see. That's a tough one to debug by sight. Something might be wrong in another function (like InitializeMaze) that only shows up when you try to use this one. Have you ever used the MonoDevelop debugger ? Its been quite a few months since I did Unity programming, but I remember using it on more than one occasion to step through code until I found the issue. You can set a break point at the function in question then see where it fails.

Comment: If you change start into `IEnumerator Start()` and add delay before running connect `yield return new WaitForSeconds(1); ConnectMaze (maze);` then it probably prints them.. it probably doesnt have time to print before hanging..

Comment: I will use the debugger and see if I'm able to find the issue, thanks.

Comment: And remove Debug.Logs inside while loop, they can hang unity also if there's tens of thousands of them.

Comment: Adding yield return new WaitForSeconds(1); before ConnectMaze() does allow unity to run without crashing, but my debug.log statements still do not appear. Nothing seems to be happening in the game.